# VRFV2Wrapper::onTokenTransfer reverts, although it shouldnt

Tags: testing, foundry, chainlink-vrf

I'm trying to test a contract "BrewBurner" which inherits VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase and should receive a a callback  to the fulfillRandomWords() function. I deploy all the contracts on the local foundry chain.
However, the VRFV2Wrapper::onTokenTransfer reverts with "only callable from Link", although the LinkToken, which is Link in this case sends the LinkToken::transferAndCall. So I do not understand why it does not work.

If I understand the traces correctly, they look fine?

[image: traces]

Comment: In the `VRFV2Wrapper` constructor are you passing the correct address for `_link`?

Comment: @ApeToshi yes I use the address of the LinkToken I deploy to the local blockchain. If I understand it correctly, it can call the function, however VRFV2Wrapper identifies the msg.sender incorrectly